# Using string constants in JPA @Column annotation

Tags: java, jpa

I am fairly new to JPA. I am trying to do something very simple.

Change...

```
@Column(name = "ITEM_NO")
private String itemNo;
```

To...

```
@Column(name = DaoConstants.ITEM_NO)
private String itemNo;
```

But when I did it I got ...

> The value for annotation attribute Column.name must be a constant expression

I am pretty sure I have used constants before with annotations. Am i wrong? Should not I use String constants with annotations?

thanks

Comment: Is `DaoConstants.ITEM_NO` static final?

Comment: I would think twice before doing that. It reduces the readability of the code more than it increases its maintainability. The constant is probably only used in this single location, and when you read the code, you now have to go to the constant definition to know what the column name is.

Comment: It's good because those constants are used elsewhere in mappers in my Apache Camel project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error indicates that DaoConstants.ITEM_NO is not declared as final. You should have something like this in `DaoConstants` class:

```
public static final String ITEM_NO = "itme_no";
```